# AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'Decision'

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to implement a CART algorithm using chefboost lib in Python. 'NetWgt' is a numeric parameter that I need to predict. Here is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import DataFrame
from chefboost import Chefboost as chef


def build_tree(dataframe: DataFrame, config: dict) -> None:
    model = chef.fit(dataframe,
                     target_label='NetWgt',
                     config=config)
    chef.save_model(model, "monthly_model.pkl")


def predict(instance) -> float:
    model = chef.load_model("monthly_model.pkl")
    prediction = chef.predict(model, instance)
    return prediction


def main():

    dataframe = pd.read_csv("monthly.csv")[['Period', 'ReporterCode', 'PartnerCode', 'NetWgt', 'PrimaryValue']]
    # dataframe = dataframe.rename(columns={"NetWgt": "Decision"})
    dataframe["NetWgt"] = dataframe["NetWgt"].astype("str")
    config = {'algorithm': 'CART', 'enableAdaboost': False}
    build_tree(dataframe.copy(), config)
    for index, instance in dataframe.iterrows():
        actual = instance['NetWgt']
        instance = instance.drop('NetWgt').to_list()
        prediction = predict(instance)
        # error = (max(prediction, actual) - min(prediction, actual)) / min(prediction, actual) * 100
        error = prediction * 100 / actual
        print(prediction, actual, error, sep=" - ")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Unfortunately, it throws an error like that:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Maryia.Zyranava.VENTION\PycharmProjects\test_chefboost.py\main.py", line 36, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\Maryia.Zyranava.VENTION\PycharmProjects\test_chefboost.py\main.py", line 25, in main
    build_tree(dataframe.copy(), config)
  File "C:\Users\Maryia.Zyranava.VENTION\PycharmProjects\test_chefboost.py\main.py", line 7, in build_tree
    model = chef.fit(dataframe,
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Maryia.Zyranava.VENTION\PycharmProjects\test_chefboost.py\venv\Lib\site-packages\chefboost\Chefboost.py", line 213, in fit
    trees = Training.buildDecisionTree(df, root = root, file = file, config = config
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Maryia.Zyranava.VENTION\PycharmProjects\test_chefboost.py\venv\Lib\site-packages\chefboost\training\Training.py", line 439, in buildDecisionTree
    else_decision = "return '%s'" % (pivot.iloc[0].Decision)
                                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Maryia.Zyranava.VENTION\PycharmProjects\test_chefboost.py\venv\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 6204, in __getattr__
    return object.__getattribute__(self, name)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'Decision'
```

Does anyone know how to fix it?

I tried to convert column type to object or string. But the problem lies somewhere inside the function buildDecisionTree.

Comment: Maybe you should consider reporting an [issue](https://github.com/serengil/chefboost/issues/new).

Answer (score 0):

You are commented a line in your main method which you need to uncomment because the `chefboost` lib is expecting the `Decision` in place of `NetWgt`

Aftar that you need to update this code:

```
for index, instance in dataframe.iterrows():
        actual = instance['NetWgt']
        instance = instance.drop('NetWgt').to_list()
```

`To`

```
for index, instance in dataframe.iterrows():
    actual = instance['Decision']
    instance = instance.drop('Decision').to_list()
```

By renaming the target column to Decision as expected by the library, the error should be resolved.